# GridView State is not getting maintained in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have Created search which search for city name with letter showing searching result in data grid view in c# window application.
I have also added a check box.
My problem is check box state not getting maintained. When i am checking the box while searching for another text, i have unchecked the check box but its not getting maintained.

Comment: In window/desktop application you not need to maintain state. I think you are binding gridview again to checkbox state not maintain ..

Comment: I think you are populating your gird every time when you filter the data? :P You should use `DataView` and its property `RowFilter`.